# Configuring multiple domain in nginx in one file

Tags: nginx

I am still newbie configuring nginx.

Is it posibble to configure multiple domain in one file and they share mostly the same config?

For example I want to configure two domains that based from one app and 
one domain need basic auth, the other doesn't.

I would like to do something like this,
but I think this does not work:

*sites-enabled/mysite*

```
server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    include sharedconf.conf;
}


server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name www.mysite.co.jp;
    auth_basic "restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx.htpasswd;
    include sharedconf.conf;
}
```

*sharedconf.conf*

```
location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    #... bunch of config line ...

}
```

Comment: The basic logic behind 2 vhosts in one file and both sharing an 'includes' sounds fine. Can you elaborate on what happens you try this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works fine.

I am assuming that you are using Debian or Debian derived Linux distribution. Then you cannot put `sharedconf.conf` into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` nor into `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, since files in those directories are included in main `nginx.conf` on Debian.

Comment: Yep, create directory like /etc/nginx/shared/ and include it via full-path. It should work without any problems. Just check permissions on directory and files

Comment: There is a ready-made /etc/nginx/snippets, exactly for this. I don't know whether it was already existed back in 2014.